# What to do with irrelevant answers?

Tags: discussion

I recently came across [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/24623/why-isnt-hybridization-done-in-america/24624#24624) that effectively should have been a comment. When I see answers like these that  really just don't answer the question at all, should I just flag it, leave a comment, or downvote it? In this case I felt the need to do all three because it was receiving upvotes (why?) and I felt the need to try to balance those out. Was this the right thing to do?

Note: at the time of flagging and whatnot, the question was not on hold.

Comment: While I haven't been around much in the last few weeks (welcome!) I'll echo Martin's answer. Do what you think is right and the community will take care of itself. :-)

Comment: If you believe the answer is useful or not useful, upvote or downvote as per the tooltips on the vote buttons. If you believe the answer fits one of the descriptions under the flag categories, then flag it. If you believe the answer can be improved, submit an edit. If there is something you'd like to say about the answer, leave a comment. When in doubt, follow the tool tips and the flag descriptions as a base criteria. Also accept that sometimes your opinion may not be the same as others' in the community, and this does not reflect on you as a person, so don't take it too seriously.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you did was just fine. However, balancing out votes should not be of any concern.

- Downvote a question when *you* think it deserves it.
- Leave a comment to request further clarification and/or why you think it should not be an answer, but something else.
- Flag as non-answer or flag for the attention of the moderators explaining your concern.

Usually you will find that these issues will be taken care of through this system.

In this special case, the question itself is a more severe problem, that's why it was closed.